# Convergence of complex sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Do the following sequences converge?

1)  $(-1)^n\frac{n}{n+i}$

2)  $\frac{n^2+in}{n^2+i}$

I don't really understand how to decide whether a complex sequence converges, and I don't have much intuition on whether either of these would.

Comment: How would you go about it if they were real sequences, say every occurrence of $i$ was replaced with $1$?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** A complex Sequence $z_n=x_n+iy_n\to z=x+iy \Leftrightarrow x_n\to x,y_n\to y$

Comment: okay so for the first one, since the real part doesn't converge, that sequence isn't convergent?

Comment: Precisely, By the way what is the real part of your first sequence?

Comment: $(-1)^nn^2/(n^2+1)$

Comment: and for the second one I have $(n^4+n)/(n^4+1) + i(n^3-n^2)/(n^4+1)$ so the real part converges to 1 and the imaginary part to 0 so the whole sequence converges?

Comment: if you are correct with your calculation ;)

Comment: I hope so! thanks for your help

Comment: you are welcome